# SpecFlow how to measure duration of each step?

Tags: c#, testing, specflow

I have long automated user cases, I want to find ways to simplify them and decrease time of their execution. I am using SpecFlow and write tests using Gherkin and C# (Selenium).

How can I get duration of each gherkin step?

Answer (score 2):

SpecFlow already outputs the duration of each step.

For example when I use the `MsTest` unit test provider, run the test inside Visual Studio 2015, click on the `Output` hyperlink in the `Test Explorer` window, I can see the following information in the `Standard Output` section:

`Given this is a step
-> done: MySteps.GivenThisIsAStep() (0.1s)
When this is another step
-> done: MySteps.WhenThisIsAnotherStep() (0.1s)
Then this is the last step
-> done: MySteps.ThenThisIsTheLastStep() (0.0s)`

Notice that the number of seconds are in parenthesis.